# Problems applying slide master to a presentation

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I'm working on reformatting a badly formatted powerpoint using a master slide layout and am having issues. First off, I need to apply a custom bullet to all 80 or so slides. I changed a master slide to reflect that but it doesn't want to take on the regular slides.

Second, the master layout has images in the bottom of the slide (company logo). When I create a new slide with the master layout, it looks fine. However, I want to keep the image placement that is already in the slides that I'm reformatting so I need to apply the master layout to the already created slides. The company logo's will not show up when I apply the master slide.

Answer (score 2):

The slide master and the slide master's layouts are two different things. If you're viewing a slide that needs changing and you choose View | Slide Master, it'll actually show you the slide's parent layout. That's what you need to change.

BUT changing the body text placeholder on the layout will only have effect if the slide's text is in a body text placeholder on the slide. Check Outline view. If the body text doesn't appear beneath the slide icon in Outline view, the text is not in a placeholder, so won't be affected by changes to the layout's body text placeholder formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you might be looking for is the "Reset Slide" option. After making changes to the Master Layout:

1. Close the "Slide Master" view
2. Make sure you are on the "Normal" view
3. Select all your slides
4. Right-click on one of them and select "Reset Slide"

The changes you made to the Master Slide should be applied

Answer (score 0):

i had this issue specifically with the footer not appearing on the notes page. I got this to work in a really strange roundabout way. Had tried re-applying notes master unsuccesfully.

Go to print the slides and choose notes pages. Then click on header and footer. choose what you want on the notes pages, header, footer page number etc. Then choose apply to all slides

[image: applying notes pages placeholders through the print headers and footers dialogue in powerpoint]

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.

Comment: Hi @DavidPostill - I shall tailor my answers - it appears though that you have deleted the posts? Were they unhelpful or not answering the question? The issue in both of the questions was the same, even though the presentation of the issue is different in the questions. Hence why the same answer can be applied to both. As far as I can see my answer is also unique so by deleting does the community not lose this solution? Thanks for taking the time to explain - as you can see from my profile, I am a long time lurker but only post solutions occasionally when the community hasn't managed to sort

Answer (score 0):

Check the background settings for the presentation!

1. Right-click the slide and select "Format Background..."
2. Uncheck the option "Hide background graphics" [image: Format Background Options]

This made the "Draft" watermark I made on the Master Slide appear throughout the whole presentation. Hope this helps!

[Add a Background Picture to Slides](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/add-a-background-picture-to-slides-4b0b98d4-774c-4e08-9c38-e8c92f58c957)